# IntelliJ: How do I run a certain maven goal before building a certain artifact?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

So, I know how to run a maven goal before/after make and before running/debugging a configuration. Sweet.

But I would like to run a maven goal before a certain artifact is built and just cannot find the option. The artifact configuration dialog allows to run an ant target, but I have no ant targets, just maven goals.

So, what do I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 options here:

1. [Submit a feature request](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issues/IDEA) to support Maven in addition to Ant in Artifact pre/post-processing.
2. Write Ant task with `exec` that will run your Maven goal and use it.